# Physical Location of images on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have used the following code to save a image in WP7:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(inkTest, null);
    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
        mediaLibrary.SavePicture("Picture.jpg", stream);
}
MessageBox.Show("Picture Saved...");
```

Now I want to download that image. Where does that image get saved in Windows? I could not find it in Program Files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Where does that image get saved in Windows? I could not find it in Program Files.

Nowhere, obviously? You're saving it to the phone's media library. If you open the Pictures hub on the phone (or emulator), you'll be able to find your picture in there, under "Saved Pictures".

The concept of a "physical location" is irrelevant for Windows Phone applications.